# Unable to install phpmyadmin due to dependency issue

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, centos, yum

I am getting this error while trying to install `phpmyadmin`.

Can someone please help me with this. I am using cent os 6.5.

I have recently done yum update too.

```
[sonill@localhost html]$ sudo yum install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpmyadmin.noarch 0:2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 4.1.0 for package: phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.i686 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Installed: php-common-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.24-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.i686 (base)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.i686 (updates)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[sonill@localhost html]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *php-common-5.4* package installed from Remi's repository but that repository is not enabled now. So when yum tries to install *php-mbstring*, newest it can find is 5.3 (from CentOS base/updates repos) which doesn't play well together with that *php-common-5.4*. So you probably need to re-enable Remi's repository and try again or install *php-mbstring-5.4* from there manually. I can see the package here:

http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/